# key in nested dictionary if it contains NaN value?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have following data in python

```
my_dictionary = {
      'key1': {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 10}, 
      'key2': {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 'NaN'}, 
      'key3': {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 12}
       ...
       ...
}
```

My Interest in to find key that has max value of C.
So far so good following code is working but it does not give correct results if 'c' has NaN value as in my case?
I wrote following code

```
max(my_dictionary, key=lambda v: my_dictionary[v]['c'])
```

what change I require in above code to account for NaN values in C?

Comment: How do you *want* it to handle `NaN`s?

Comment: Your `'NaN'` is a string.  If you really want NaN, use `float('nan')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could give a default value for the NaNs:

```
print(max(my_dictionary, key=lambda v: my_dictionary[v]['c'] 
     if isinstance(my_dictionary[v]['c'],int) else float("-inf")))
```

You can also use a function to pass as the key instead of looking up the value twice and use `Number` to handle the case where you have more than just ints:

```
from numbers import Number
def key(x):
    val = my_dictionary[x]['c']
    return  val if isinstance(val, Number) else float("-inf")
print(max(my_dictionary, key=key))
```

Comment: I was just writing something alike, but I wanted to use -sys.maxint/maxsize. You version is better, -inf will be smaller than anything. Also, use https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/math.html#math.isnan to find NaNs. You have my sword. Any my bow. And my upvote.

Comment: @khan, just `mx = max(my_dictionary, key=key))`, the same for the first code `mx = max(my_dictionary, key=lambda v: my_dictionary[v]['c'] 
     if isinstance(my_dictionary[v]['c'],int) else float("-inf")))`